# access DLookUp multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

having trouble with this DlookUp expression it evaluates the first criteria but not the other two, any advice would be great.

App_Ref is a text box,
PRB responsable is a string,
AppCostAdmend is a string

```
 =DLookUp("[Var_Amount]","Variations","[Var_AppRef] =[App_Ref]" And "[Var_Type] =  'AppCostAdmend'" And "[Var_Description] = 'PRB responsable'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` has to be part of the criteria too! It works like a SELECT with WHERE ... AND ...!

So:

```
=DLookUp("[Var_Amount]","Variations","[Var_AppRef] =[App_Ref] And [Var_Type] =  'AppCostAdmend' And [Var_Description] = 'PRB responsable'")
```