# Access 2013 Prevent Duplicate Record on Save

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation, ms-access-2013

So I have an entry form like so, [New Visitor Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v10Y8.png)

I am trying to prevent it from saving a record if visitor is already in the table. This is what I have tried, but not having much luck. It will match from different records. I am open to any suggestions.

```
Dim FName As String
Dim LName As String
Dim CName As String
Dim stLinkCriteriaFN As String
Dim stLinkCriteriaLN As String
Dim stLinkCriteriaCN As String

If IsNull(Me.tbFirstName.Value) Or IsNull(Me.tbLastName.Value) Or IsNull(Me.cbCompany.Value) Then
MsgBox "Not all information has been entered, visitor was not added.", vbOKOnly, "Data Entry Error"
Else

LName = Me.tbLastName.Value
FName = Me.tbFirstName.Value
CName = Me.cbCompany.Value



stLinkCriteriaLN = "[LastName] = " & "'" & LName & "'"
stLinkCriteriaFN = "[FirstName] = " & "'" & FName & "'"
stLinkCriteriaCN = "[Company] = " & "'" & CName & "'"


 If Me.tbLastName = DLookup("[LastName]", "VisitorInfo", stLinkCriteriaLN) And Me.tbFirstName = DLookup("[FirstName]", "VisitorInfo", stLinkCriteriaFN) And Me.cbCompany = DLookup("[Company]", "VisitorInfo", stLinkCriteriaCN) Then
    MsgBox "Visitor Already Added", vbOKOnly
 Else
    Dim f As Form
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    For Each f In Access.Forms
    f.Requery
    Next
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdClose
 End If
End If
```

Comment: Use one DLookup and combine the criteria. I think the following might give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378081/access-dlookup-multiple-criteria

Comment: Don't see the connection how that would be used to compare the values from the current record to prevent a save. @PKatona

Comment: I was hoping you'd look at the Cell DLookup macro where it combined multiple criteria and extrapolate into VBA as I've done for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some sort of primary key in the VisitorInfo table, you combine the criteria and examine the DLookup results something like this:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[VisitorID]", "VisitorInfo", "[LastName] = '" & LName & "' AND [FirstName] = '" & FName & "' AND [Company] = '" & CName & "'") Then
    Dim f As Form
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    For Each f In Access.Forms
        f.Requery
    Next
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdClose
Else
    MsgBox "Visitor Already Added", vbOKOnly
End If
```

Comment: `If DLookup("[VisitorID]", "VisitorInfo", "[LastName] = '" & LName & "' AND [FirstName] = '" & FName & "' AND [Company] = '" & CName & "'") Is Nothing Then`  I tried yours and it had a compile error. Tried this approach and have a 424 Error.

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your table? You would need to replace "VisitorId" with the name of your primary key.

Comment: Yes I do and it is VisitorID.

Comment: An error 424 happens when you refer to an object property or method that is not defined. Do you know which line the error occurs on? If not, can you run debug and note which line it occurs on?

Comment: Fixed the answer.